# How do i rewrite my URL in asp.net MVC to make it more SEO friendly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have a small website where i need some url rewriting. Im making a small generic site to help me host subsites for sports. I made one site that should fit all.

When i link to a particular sport, eg. football it now looks like this:

/home/show/3

What i really want it to look like is this

/home/sports/football

How do i go about doing this? Can it be configured so that on another website i could show books like this: /home/books/thriller etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add Entry to Routing Table as

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{cat}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", cat = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Now. On your view or controller write your code, to set the id for proceesing in your code.

```
var id = 0;
    if (Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["cat"] != null)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("cat"), out id) == false)
        {
            string routeName = Request.RequestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("cat");
            id = new RoutingRepository().GetTabIDByRoute(routeName); // here you need to get the id for text passed in url
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that adding an additional route? Default i have controller/action/id - should i also have one controller/action/cat - and handle both?

Comment: It depends... but you just replace it with the one you already have